# List all numbers between 2 negative decimal numbers

Tags: python, numpy, range

How to get a list of all numbers between 2 negative decimal numbers.

Note that the scale could be 2 or 5 decimal places with precision not more than 3. (i dont know if this matter)

For Ex Given 1 Negative Decimal and and other Negative Decimal:

`[-0.05 and -0.02 ]` with step `0.01`

Output :

`[-0.04,-0.03]`

Or for example 1 Negative Decimal and 1 Positive Decimal:

`[-0.05 and 0.05 ]` with step `0.01`

Output :

`[-0.04,-0.03,-0.02,-0.01,0.00,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05]`

Tried [range(](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)) and also [xrange()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) with negative step and got nothing.

With [numpy.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) i got strange results.

Comment: What were your *strange results* using `np.arange` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
min_value = -0.05
max_value = 0.05
step = 0.01
output_list = [elem/100000.0 for elem in range(int(min_value*100000), int((max_value+step)*100000), int(step*100000))]
# outputs [-0.05, -0.04, -0.03, -0.02, -0.01, 0.0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]
```

Explanation:

`range` works with integers, and you said the max precision you wanted was 3. So, by multiplying times 1000 (for 3 decimals) and casting to `integer` you can use the function. All that's left is to divide de rsults by 1000 again, to get the desired scale.

Also, since the max_value is not included by the range function, I added the step to include it as well, therefore using `(max_value+step)*1000`. You can do the same with `min_value` to exclude it.

Comment: Done. Updated it

Comment: Thanks but i got strage results `min_value = -0.00015
max_value = 0.05` note that the 2 numbers might not be equal in precision and scale. i should have mention it .

Comment: In that case, which would be the step you wish to use?

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.arange` has good results `float` calculations always has tiny error.

```
import numpy as np

begin  = -0.05
finish = 0.05
step   = 0.01

np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(np.arange(begin+step, finish, step))
```

The output is:

```
[ -4.000e-02  -3.000e-02  -2.000e-02  -1.000e-02   6.939e-18   1.000e-02
   2.000e-02   3.000e-02   4.000e-02]
```

Where `-4.000e-02` means `(-4)*10^(-2)` or `0.04`. And `6.939e-18` means `6.939*10^(-18)` or almost zero.

There is another way:

```
begin = -0.05
finish = -0.02
step = 0.01
l = [begin+(i+1)*step for i in range(round((finish-begin)/step)-1)]
print(l)
```

The output is:

```
[-0.04, -0.030000000000000002]
```